# Find all triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers such that $(1+\frac{1}{a})(1+\frac{1}{b})(1+\frac{1}{c})=3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, inequality

> **Find all triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers such that $(1+\frac{1}{a})(1+\frac{1}{b})(1+\frac{1}{c})=3$**

Supposing $a\ge b\ge c$, $$(1+\frac{1}{c})^3\ge 3$$ $$\Rightarrow 1 + \frac{1}{c^3} + 3(1 + \frac{1}{c})\frac{1}{c} \ge3 $$
After this how to proceed?

Comment: starting with $a\geq b\geq c$ is a good idea, but in this way you can not get triples, I guess

Comment: Since $(1+ \frac{1}{3})^3 < 3$, you must have $c\le 2$.